# Convincing GHC that `Maybe Void` is a unit type

Tags: haskell, void, type-families

I have a type family `IfEq (n :: Nat) (m :: Nat) o` that evaluates to `o` or `Void` depending on wether `n :== m`. Since `Maybe Void` is only inibited by `Nothing` I should be able to define a function `Maybe (IfEq n m o) -> Maybe o` but I can't figure it out.

Follow up: Can this generalized from the `Maybe` monad to a more general type? (eg. all `MonadPlus`s)

EDIT: I had initially rolled my own `Nat` but (thank's to @chi) with the GHC `Nat` kind `KnownNat` constrait it pretty straightforward to do what I describe above. However GHC can not infer `KnownNat a => KnownNat (1+a)` which is imperative to me so I am back at square 1.

Comment: You cannot define such a function (well, you can simply have `Just x = error ..` but I suppose you are looking for a type safe way of doing this) because you cannot pattern match on a type. At least you would need `Typeable (IfEq n m o) => Maybe (IfEq n m o) -> Maybe o`. The general strategy is to use singletons.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
foo :: forall n m o . (KnownNat n, KnownNat m) =>
       IfEq n m o -> Maybe o
foo x = case sameNat (Proxy :: Proxy n) (Proxy :: Proxy m) of
   Just Refl -> Just x
   Nothing -> Nothing
```

Comment: I didn't think it was important but I had rolled my own `data Nat = Suc Nat | Zero`. Is it possible to infer `KnownNat a => KnownNat (1 + a)`?

Comment: @fakedrake I think your actual issue is that, at runtime, the type-level naturals `n,m` are not stored in memory, so we can't use them. We need them to be present at runtime, either through a typeclass dictionary, or through an explicit singleton argument. (About `KnownNat`, I don't know how it works in precise terms)

Comment: Well that is exactly the point, I expect those numbers to be calculated at compile time and then use them to compute the correct types. All relevant info must be available at compile time. Is it unreasonable to think that if I know `a :: Nat` at compile time I can also know `1 + a`?

Comment: To provide some context (which is much too large to fit in detail in this question), I have a class of recursive generic types that have the form `Expr a = Expr0 a | Expr1 Op1 (Expr a) | Expr2 Op2 (Expr a) (Expr a) | ... deriving Generic1` and the end goal is to generate polymorphic functions to extract the operator if it's there `getOp :: (Algebra expr, KnownNat arity) => (arity :: Nat) -> expr a -> Maybe (OpAtArity arity (expr a))`.

Comment: Turns out GHC can actually infer `KnownNat (1 + n)` but you need to explicitly ask for it. I also found a [GHC plugin](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-typelits-knownnat) that removes that overhead.